# The ArrayList in this fragment is initialised to null after switching to landscape mode for the second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

When I change orientation from `portrait` to `landscape` the shown `ArrayList` becomes `null`. When I start in `landscape` mode everything works fine but when I change to `portrait` and back to `landscape` the given array list becomes `null`. I am passing data using `bundles`. I am using 2 layouts if that helps.

As can be seen from the log, the ArrayList received in getArgs method is not null but still, the same ArrayList becomes null in onActivityCreated. When I again change back to Portrait everything works as it should. I have no clue as to what is happening.

```
public class ListFrag extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerview;
RecyclerView.Adapter myadapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
View view;
ArrayList<Subject> subjects;

public ListFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: Fragment created");
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerview =view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    if(subjects==null) {
        subjects= new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated: Subjects is null");
        subjects.add(new Subject("New Subject"));
    }
    myadapter = new SubjectAdapter(this.getActivity(), subjects);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(myadapter);
}

//This is a bundle from the main activity, it contains the local subjects //ArrayList.

public void getArgs(Bundle args){
    subjects= args.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
    Log.d(TAG, "getArgs: Bundle Recieved");
    if(subjects!=null)
        Log.d(TAG, "getArgs: "+subjects.get(1).getSub_name());
}
}
```

I am showing the log when I change from landscape <-> portrait <-> landscape. As can be seen, when the orientation is landscape for the 2nd time the ArrayList subjects become null.

```
D/Constraints: onCreateView: Fragment created
D/Constraints: getArgs: Bundle Recieved

D/Constraints: getArgs: PCE // There is no subjects is null log i.e. working as expected.

W/Activity: Slow Operation: Activity com.kinshuu.silverbook/.MainActivity onCreate took 573ms

I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : cf57c9c, I1cb5c4d1cc
Build Date                       : 09/23/18
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
Local Branch                     : 
Remote Branch                    : 
Remote Branch                    : 
Reconstruct Branch               : 
Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64

I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066

I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay 
retrieved: 0
android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0

I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2

I/Choreographer: Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1356ms; Flags=0, 
IntendedVsync=97223951567176, Vsync=97224984900468, 
OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, 
HandleInputStart=97224993787166, AnimationStart=97224993944978, 
PerformTraversalsStart=97224996071280, DrawStart=97225005895864, 
SyncQueued=97225058785291, SyncStart=97225058907843, 
IssueDrawCommandsStart=97225059050708, SwapBuffers=97225304631072, 
FrameCompleted=97225307792895, DequeueBufferDuration=8842000, 
QueueBufferDuration=955000, 

I/shuu.silverboo: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=10 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000

W/shuu.silverboo: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)

W/Activity: Slow Operation: Activity com.kinshuu.silverbook/.MainActivity onPause took 227ms

D/Constraints: onCreateView: Fragment created

D/Constraints: getArgs: Bundle Received
getArgs: PCE //changed to portrait for the first time, nothing surprising here.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1046ms; Flags=0, 
IntendedVsync=97235972493579, Vsync=97236939160207, 
OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, 
HandleInputStart=97236951083724, AnimationStart=97236951267578, 
PerformTraversalsStart=97236953417578, DrawStart=97236962640547, 
SyncQueued=97237012391797, SyncStart=97237012495547, 
IssueDrawCommandsStart=97237012607734, SwapBuffers=97237017997109, 
FrameCompleted=97237019035807, DequeueBufferDuration=2937000, 
QueueBufferDuration=532000, 

D/Constraints: onCreateView: Fragment created

D/Constraints: getArgs: Bundle Received

D/Constraints: getArgs: PCE//subjects is not null

D/Constraints: onActivityCreated: Subjects is null // And subjects is null at the same time.

I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.}
```

Comment: Where is the Bundle args stored? you need to save the state of the Activity (plus fragments if you not doing there) at onSaveInstanceState from activity, plus, if you use Fragment.setArguments you will have the same ArrayList through orientation changes (but not updated values that will need save instance as well) that happens, because your screen is being DESTROYED and reconstructed but you don't have the objects of the older state saved

Comment: Thats the reason that onCreate of Activity have the Bundle savedInstanceState as argument

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Sir but as can be seen in the log, at one place the list is not null and in onActivityCreated its null.

Comment: You have to use onSaveInstanceState and save the list there cause its a local variable that will be erased onDestroy and you can get at onCreate the bundle will contain the saved state (ps it will be null if has no saved state)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Sir I tried OnSavedInstance but there also i am facing the same problem. The ArrayList i am passing in savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList() is null. But the ArrayList i recieve from getArgs method is not null.

Comment: you forgetting to initalize it somewhere, we can only see if you post code

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Sir i have already posted my code and the log with the question. Please see

Comment: Where you do call getArgs? you need to add the activity too